# Clamp UVs checkbox disappeared?

Tags: unreal, materials

I've run into the following problem. I'm following some tutorials for shading to the exact letter.
It all works except my meshes have really bad shadowing in/on them.

I see the difference with the tutorial: the Clamp UVs checkbox in the SceneTexture nodes has disappeared from the material editor GUI.. How should I replace this function? I already have some clamps in my blueprint but they are also part of the tutorial so they aren't there to replace the checkbox that disappeared under "Scene Texture Id".

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I was dividing SceneTexture: DiffuseColor by SceneTexture: PostProcessInput0 instead of the other way around. Fixed ! (Just thought I'd post my own answer for anyone who ever stumbles unto the same issue)